# Dynamic naming for AWS EC2 instances launched by Terraform aws_autoscaling_group

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, autoscaling

I have successfully created an autoscaling group using Terraform. I would like to now find a way to dynamically name the provisioned instances based on index value.

For an `aws_instance` type, it can be easily done by:

```
resource "aws_instance" "bar" {
  count = 3

  tags {
    Name     = "${var.instance_name_gridNode}${count.index + 1}"
    App-code = "${var.app-code}"
    PC-code  = "${var.pc-code}"
  }
}
```

This will result in 3 instances named:

1) Node1

2) Node2

3) Node3

However as `aws_autoscaling_group` is dynamically provisioned (for both scaling in and out situations) how does one control the naming convention of the provisioned instances?

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "gridrouter_asg" {
  name                      = "mygridrouter"
  launch_configuration      = "${aws_launch_configuration.gridGgr_lcfg.id}"
  min_size                  = 1
  max_size                  = 2
  health_check_grace_period = 150
  desired_capacity          = 1
  vpc_zone_identifier       = ["${var.subnet_id}"]
  health_check_type         = "EC2"

  tags = [
    {
      key                 = "Name"
      value               = "${var.instance_name_gridGgr_auto}"
      propagate_at_launch = true
    },
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

AWS autoscaling groups can be tagged as with many resources and using the `propagate_at_launch` flag those tags will also be passed to the instances that it creates.

Unfortunately these are entirely static and the ASG itself has no way of tagging instances differently. On top of this the [default scale in policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-instance-termination.html#default-termination-policy) will not remove the newest instances first so even if you did tag your instances as `Node1`, `Node2`, `Node3` then when the autoscaling group scaled in it's most likely (depending on criteria) to remove `Node1` leaving you with `Node2` and `Node3`. While it's possible to change the termination policy to `NewestInstance` so that it would remove `Node3` this is unlikely to be an optimal scale in policy.

I'd question why you feel you need to take ASG instances differently from each other and maybe rethink about how you manage your instances when they are more ephemeral as is generally the case in modern clouds but more so when using autoscaling groups.

If you really did want to tag instances differently for some specific reason you could have the ASG not propagate the `Name` tag at launch to instances and then have a Lambda function trigger on the scale out event (either via a lifecycle hook or a Cloudwatch event) to determine the tag value to use and then tag the instance with it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate the answer :-)

Answer (score 3):

One hack to do this is to pass the user-data script to the instance or autoscaling-group. 
PFB the link to the answer to a similar question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44613778/3304632