# Unique custom ID for each instance in AWS autoscaling group using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, autoscaling

I am creating an AWS autoscaling group dynamically using ruby scripts and shell scripts. After the instances in ASG boot up, I am running a task in them in the `user_data` scripts. Let's say I have created 10 instances in the auto scaling group. I want to number these instances somehow (may be using tags or environment variables, etc.). So each instance will have an environment variable named "number" with its value being 1, 2, 3...10, unique for each instance.

We can attach the `tags` with the instances as shown below:

```
resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "autoscaling_group" {
  name = "${var.asg_name}"
  max_size = "${var.max_size}"
  min_size = "${var.min_size}"
  desired_capacity = "${var.desired_capacity}"
  launch_configuration = "${aws_launch_configuration.launch_configuration.name}"
  vpc_zone_identifier = ["${data.aws_subnet_ids.default.ids}"]

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

  tag {
    key = "Environment"
    value = "production"
    propagate_at_launch = true
  }
}
```

But I would like to attach a tag "number" with its different value with each instance.

Or we can also send variables in `user_data` scripts as shown below:

```
data "template_file" "user_data_client" {
  template = "${file("./user-data-client.sh")}"

  vars {
    company_location_job_id   = "${var.company_location_job_id}"
    docker_login_username = "${var.docker_login_username}"
    docker_login_password = "${var.docker_login_password}"
  }
}
```

But here also, I am not sure how to send incremental numbers for each instance in a variable.

Is it possible to do this using terraform ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question has popped up before and I asked this then too but why do you want to tag your ASG instances differently?

Comment: Each of my ASG instance is running a rails rake task. The rake task requires an integer argument that will pick records from database and run some ruby script on them. Since each of my instance should process a different set of records, that is why I want to tag each instance differently so that I can use that tag to pass argument to the rake task.

Comment: I read your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44609595/set-a-unique-tag-to-each-instance-of-terraform-aws-autoscaling-group-module. Did not find it earlier. Retagging the instance in user_data script might work but as you rightly said, it may assign a wrong tag since AWS autoscaling group may create 2 instances simultaneously.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set a unique tag to each instance of Terraform aws\_autoscaling\_group module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44609595/set-a-unique-tag-to-each-instance-of-terraform-aws-autoscaling-group-module)